# What is the best way to do X^2= 618

Tags: exponential-function, radicals

What would be the best and easiest way to do X^2 = 618 (Without a calculator)
Wouldn't it just be considered irrational
(Solving for x)

Comment: $25\times 25 = 625$

Comment: "*To do x^2=618*"  What do you mean by "to do" here?  To solve for $x$?  To what level of precision?  Will $x$ in $x^2=618$ be irrational?  Yes.  Can you solve for the first several digits by hand?  Also yes.  Can you solve for *all* digits?  No, but neither could a calculator, but you could solve for as many digits as you wished.

Comment: @JMoravitz Solve for x

Comment: You only acknowledged the first two sentences of my comment.  Read and respond to the rest.

Comment: As @hamam_Abdallah wrote $25^2 = 625 > 618$ and also $24^2 = 576 < 618$. Therefore $24 < x < 25$. Now, to narrow this range down, compare $x^2$ and $24.5^2$. You can continue the halving the range to get more and more precise approximation of $x$. This process is known as the [Bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method).

Comment: If you want to calculate square roots of numbers expressed in decimal by hand, this wikipedia page tells you how to do it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Digit-by-digit_calculation. (Personal aside: I was taught long division at school and have never forgotten how to do it, but I always have to look up the square root algorithm.)

Answer (score 2):

You want to find the positive zero of function
$$f(x)=x^2-618$$ Notice that
$f(25)=7$ and the $f''(x) > ~~ \forall x$. Then, by Darboux theorem, Newton method will converge without overshooting the solution at any time.

So, starting with $x_0=25$, perform the iterations
$$x_{n+1}= x_n-\frac{x_n^2-618}{2 x_n}$$ This would generate the sequence
$$\left\{25,\frac{1243}{50},\frac{3090049}{124300}\right\}$$ Notice that
$$\frac{1243}{50}=24.86 \qquad \text{while} \qquad \sqrt{618}=24.8596\cdots$$

I do not see the problem to get the first iterate by hand.

Sooner or later, you will learn about methods of higher order. Fo example, Halley method would give for its first iteration
$$\frac{61975}{2493}=24.8596069\qquad \text{while} \qquad  \sqrt{618}=24.8596058$$ I made it by hand.